# pass object to method as parameter

Tags: php, oop

I need Create a PHP method that pass object to method as parameter look like this

```
$status = $myClass -> mymethod({

    server : "localhost",
    user : "user",
    password : '123'

 })
```

How should I design this method ??

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cast` them from `array` to `object` -

```
$status = $myClass ->mymethod(
   (object)[
    "server" => "localhost",
    "user" => "user",
    "password" => '123'
   ]
);
```

And the method would be -

```
public function mymethod($object)
{
    echo $object->server; // or whatever processing you need
}
```

Comment: *How should I design this method ??* And how should OP design his method ? You only showed how to call the method, but now what's inside of it

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast an array to an object:

```
<?php
Class myClass {

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function mymethod($obj){
        return $obj;
    }

}

$status = (new myClass())->mymethod(
    (object)array(
        "server" => "localhost",
        "user" => "user",
        "password" => '123'
    )
);

var_dump($status); 
/* RETURNS:

object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
  ["server"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["user"]=>
  string(4) "user"
  ["password"]=>
  string(3) "123"
}

*/
```